# ORA-9005: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, keyword

I'm getting an ORA-9005: missing keyword error when I'm trying to execute the below query.

```
select a.OBJID,
       A.TITLE,
       a.id_number,
       a.creation_time,
       a.case_reporter2contact,
       a.x_rev_esc_prim_reason,
       a.x_rev_esc_sec_reason,
       a.x_esc_third_reason,
       b.x_channel_source,
       b.x_verification,
       b.x_followup_status,
       b.x_saves_status,
       b.x_saves_reason,
       b.x_cust_mislead_flag,
       b.x_cust_mislead_reason,
       b.x_create_dt,
       b.x_update_dt
  from table_case a, table_x_saves_case_info b
 INNER JOIN (SELECT case_reporter2contact,
                    MAX(trunc(creation_time)) as latest_date
               FROM table_case
              WHERE calltype2gbst_elm = '268436012'
                AND x_activity_code = 'DO Drop Off'
              GROUP BY case_reporter2contact) as q
    ON a.case_reporter2contact = q.case_reporter2contact
   and q.latest_date > trunc(a.creation_time)
 where a.objid = b.x_saves_case_info2case
   and a.x_esc_primary_reason = 'Rental Inbound'
   and a.x_esc_secondary_reason in ('Buy-Out', 'Pick-Up', 'Drop-Off')
   and b.x_channel_source in ('Third Party Call',
                              'Third Party Email',
                              'Third Party Fax',
                              'Third Party Mail')
   and b.x_followup_status in ('2nd Attempt Complete', 'Complete')
 order by b.x_create_dt DESC
```

It's highlighting the 'AS' from

MAX(trunc(creation_time)) as latest_date

and

GROUP BY case_reporter2contact) as q

on oracle 10g

Comment: if you alias the table "TABLE_CASE" and apply that to the select does it work?  as in  SELECT a.case_reportercontact,....from TABLE_CASE a

Comment: sorry kevnisky..  i'm not following.. do you mean like this? 

from "TABLE_CASE" a, table_x_saves_case_info b and FROM "TABLE_CASE".  If so, no it doesn't work, same result.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you cannot use the "AS" keyword when aliasing tables or inline views.

Therefore your query needs to be:

```
select a.OBJID, A.TITLE, a.id_number, a.creation_time, a.case_reporter2contact, 
a.x_rev_esc_prim_reason, a.x_rev_esc_sec_reason, a.x_esc_third_reason, 
b.x_channel_source, b.x_verification, b.x_followup_status, b.x_saves_status, 
b.x_saves_reason, b.x_cust_mislead_flag, b.x_cust_mislead_reason, b.x_create_dt, 
b.x_update_dt 
from table_case a, table_x_saves_case_info b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT case_reporter2contact, MAX(trunc(creation_time)) as latest_date
    FROM table_case
    WHERE calltype2gbst_elm = '268436012' 
        AND x_activity_code = 'DO Drop Off'
        GROUP BY case_reporter2contact) q -- removed the AS keyword from here
ON a.case_reporter2contact = q.case_reporter2contact and q.latest_date > trunc(a.creation_time)
where a.objid = b.x_saves_case_info2case
and a.x_esc_primary_reason = 'Rental Inbound'
and a.x_esc_secondary_reason in ('Buy-Out','Pick-Up','Drop-Off')
and b.x_channel_source in ('Third Party Call','Third Party Email','Third Party Fax','Third Party Mail')
and b.x_followup_status in ('2nd Attempt Complete','Complete')
order by b.x_create_dt DESC
```

Comment: removed the AS keyword and it came back with another error - ORA-00904: "A"."CREATION_TIME": invalid identifier

Comment: does that column exist in table_case?

Comment: Ah, I suspect the issue may be that you're mixing up ANSI joins with implicit joins. Convert the join between table_case and table_x_saves_case_info into ANSI join syntax and you should find that it works.

Comment: how do you convert the join between table_case and table_x_saves_case_info into ANSI join syntax?

Comment: You see how you have an inner join from q to a, but you have a comma after the a, with a corresponding join condition from a to b in the where clause? Make the join from a to b look like that of a to q.

Comment: my apologies..  i'm still learning here, and i'm not really understanding your last comment.  Do you think you're able to edit your solution?  so i can copy and paste to see if it works?  Also, can you please highlight or indicate the join conversion, so i'll know what to look for.  thanks Boneist!

Comment: I'm not in the office, sorry. Anyway, ANSI join syntax is when you specify the join condition as part of the from clause, eg `select * from a inner join b on (a.col = b.col)` and implicit joins are when you list the tables in the from clause and specify the join clause as part of the where clause, eg `select * from a, b where a.col = b.col`. Alternatively you can google ANSI joins

Comment: You need to do explicty INNER JOIN between "table_case a, table_x_saves_case_info b" using this clause "a.objid = b.x_saves_case_info2case". Like: "from table_case a INNER JOIN table_x_saves_case_info b on a.objid = b.x_saves_case_info2case"

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got it working. In future try not to mix the join styles; stick to one or the other. You've already seen that there are subtle gotchas if you mix them! *{:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.OBJID,
       a.TITLE,
       a.id_number,
       a.creation_time,
       a.case_reporter2contact,
       a.x_rev_esc_prim_reason,
       a.x_rev_esc_sec_reason,
       a.x_esc_third_reason,
       b.x_channel_source,
       b.x_verification,
       b.x_followup_status,
       b.x_saves_status,
       b.x_saves_reason,
       b.x_cust_mislead_flag,
       b.x_cust_mislead_reason,
       b.x_create_dt,
       b.x_update_dt
  from table_case a inner join table_x_saves_case_info b on a.objid = b.x_saves_case_info2case
 INNER JOIN (SELECT case_reporter2contact,
                    MAX(trunc(creation_time)) as latest_date
               FROM table_case
              WHERE calltype2gbst_elm = '268436012'
                AND x_activity_code = 'DO Drop Off'
              GROUP BY case_reporter2contact) q
    ON a.case_reporter2contact = q.case_reporter2contact
   and q.latest_date > trunc(a.creation_time)
   where a.calltype2gbst_elm = '268438297'
   and a.x_esc_primary_reason = 'Rental Inbound'
   and a.x_esc_secondary_reason in ('Buy-Out', 'Pick-Up', 'Drop-Off')
   and b.x_channel_source in ('Third Party Call',
                              'Third Party Email',
                              'Third Party Fax',
                              'Third Party Mail')
   and b.x_followup_status in ('2nd Attempt Complete', 'Complete')
 order by b.x_create_dt DESC
```